# Storing Files for One-Time Downloads

Tags: php, mysql, file

I'm working on a side project at the moment and I want users to be able to download a file under a condition but I don't want them to have a link to the video. They should only be able to download the file once and then have it be impossible (unless conditions are met) to access the file again.

I thought about storing it on the server however if they got the file name and path, they could download it whenever they want and/or share it. I then thought about adding the files to a SQL Database but that doesn't seem too efficient or effective.

What is the best way to store a file that can ensure a one time download? I'm using PHP if that makes any difference.

Comment: What's the file type?

Comment: I think they're overused by some people but using a GUID to generate a temporary download folder on the server, and deleting it afterward of course, might be the simplest solution.

Comment: @MariM I didn't think it'd matter by most `mp4` and `mov`

Comment: you dont even need to do that. store the files outside the webroot, control access to them via a download script which requires a key. revoke the key after its used and the download is complete.

Answer (score 0):

My recommondation would be to use a PHP call as "gateway".

Let the user call a PHP-Script with Parameter and then check the permissions within the script. After a successfull check of his permissions (via Session / cookie validation i.e.) you can manipulate the header of the PHP-Script to return the requested rescoure. 
I use this for images alot.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php